# How to update in one line rather than multiple?

Tags: java, optimization

Simple, I just want a code that (instead of printing out individual lines of text in the console) update just one line of text with the new values, or "replace" it.

**Current Code:**

```
//this code was expanded into a more configurable version
//original author is zengr

public final class EnumRandValue {

public static final void main(String... aArgs){
int min = 12;
int max = 157;
int ints = 1000;
//how many numbers to generate?

int enumeration = 1;
int maximumints = 1000;
//advanced users only!

log("Generating " + ints + " random integers in range of " + (min-1) + " and " + (max-1) + ".");

//note a single Random object is reused here
if(min < max || min != max) {
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= ints; ++idx){
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
  log("E" + enumeration++ + ": " + randomInt);
  if(enumeration >= maximumints) {
      String breakmsg = "Exceeded enums limit (" + maximumints + ").";
      log(breakmsg);
      return;

  } else if(min >= max) {
  String breakmsg = "Invalid min/max values.";
  log(breakmsg);
  return;     

  } else {
  //really nothing happens here
  //some code was excluded
```

Comment: whats expected here? and what is the code about that you've shared/

Comment: What is `log()`?

Comment: it just generates a list of random numbers using min and max. it's output looks like this:

`Generating 10 random integers in range of 11 and 156.
E1: 50
E2: 15
E3: 115
E4: 142
E5: 133
E6: 55
E7: 59
E8: 138
E9: 134
E10: 45`

Comment: Instead, would it be possible to return the latest string of the for loop only? So it would only return two lines, `Generating 10 random integers in range of 11 and 156. E10: 47`

Comment: log() is what outputs the results to the console as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your log() method is a static method that prints the string that is passed to it.

In that case if you just want to print the last line of your for loop check the below condition before your print.

```
if(idx==ints)
log("E" + enumeration++ + ": " + randomInt);
```

Comment: did i use it correctly?

`if(min < max || min != max) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= ints; ++idx){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
      if(idx==ints) {
      log("E" + enumeration++ + ": " + randomInt);
      }
      if(enumeration >= maximumints) {
       String breakmsg = "Exceeded enums limit (" + maximumints + ").";
       log(breakmsg);
       return;`

it only returns the first enumeration

Comment: it doesn't seem to be updating (or running constantly until reaching the limit/desired amount) either